# calculated double return scientific notation

Tags: ios, swift

i'm calculating a price using two doubles, however when i output it seem to return it as scientific notation with like `1.785e-05`. This is however not intended how do i make sure thats this output it with 8 decimals and not scientific notation?

**CODE**

```
let price = tickerObj.price ?? 0
let quantity = Double(self.activeTextField.text ?? "0") ?? 0
let value = quantity / price

topValueField.text = "\(value.rounded(toPlaces: 8))"
```

**ROUND EXTENSION**

```
extension Double {
    /// Rounds the double to decimal places value
    func rounded(toPlaces places:Int) -> Double {
        let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
        return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `NumberFormatter` ...

Comment: What is the actual value of `value`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number itself is correct as scientific notation.  If you want to present a formatted number to the user, it should be a String. Here's working code using a NumberFormatter:

```
extension Double {
    /// Rounds the double to decimal places value
    func rounded(toPlaces places:Int) -> String? {
        let fmt = NumberFormatter()
        fmt.numberStyle = .decimal
        fmt.maximumFractionDigits = places
        return fmt.string(from: self as NSNumber)
    }
}

let price = tickerObj.price ?? 0
let quantity = Double(self.activeTextField.text ?? "0") ?? 0
let value = quantity / price

topValueField.text = "\(value.rounded(toPlaces: 8) ?? "Unknown")"
```

Comment: For a method named `rounded(toPlaces:)`, do you really think the comment "Rounds the double to decimal places value" is necessary?

Comment: @Alexander that was his name, not mine.